# Apache2 conflict on home server with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2

I followed steps to install Ubuntu server on a home machine. This included installing Apache2 and Mysql. I also installed Nextcloud via Snap.

Whenever I start/reboot my server machine I can not access my Nextcloud via a browser (using server fixed IP). What I get is an Apache2 splash screen. If I SSH into the server and run 'sudo systemctl stop apache2' and then refresh my browser I can then access my Nextcloud.

I am thinking there is a conflict between the manually installed apache2 and the snap install but I am just a beginner. I would think I should be able to have both as I may install other things outside of Snap. BTW - I connect via http and just within my local home network though I desire to eventually get my server accessible remotely once I learn how to do so. I would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: You do not need Apache to be installed on the server if NextCloud is the only service that is being run. The Snap will take care of everything itself. If you plan on running multiple sites from this server *plus* NextCloud as a Snap, I would strongly suggest installing NextCloud as a standard PHP package and going from there. You could set up reverse proxies and other complicated things, but it quickly becomes too much to manage for most people.

Comment: I want to be sure I don't hurt my snap install. Do you suggest the following comands? "apt-get purge apache2"     
"apt-get autoremove" and then "sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2"?  I found these in another post.

Comment: `sudo apt purge apache2-data && sudo apt autoremove` and then accepting the removal of the rest of the Apache2 bits via purge should work.  `apache2-data` or `apache2-common` are required for ALL the apache bits to work, remove that and all the other packages will be removed too.  That'll erase the config left-over as well.